# Computed style sizes incorrect in Chrome

Tags: css, browser

I know there are similar existing questions but none of them have answers which I'm looking for.

I have a div with a height of 20px and a width of 11px. But when I try to get the height and width of it with getComputedStyle(), Chrome returns a height of 19.992px where as Firefox returns the correct value. My Browser Zoom is set to 100% (default).

If you try to open this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dL65nmrg/4/) in Chrome and Firefox, you can see the difference.

```
//style.css
div{
  height: 20px;
  width: 11px;
  background: red;
}

//script.js
const div = document.querySelector("div");

const text = document.querySelector("p");

text.textContent = "Height: " + window.getComputedStyle(div).height;
```

Why are there differences or what causes it?

---

**Updated with images**

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Comment: FWIW my browsers all report 20px. Windows 10 desktop, 1 hardware dot per pixel.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, Safari - all show 20px on macOS

Comment: May be sharing the screenshot can help, wherein you are getting height as 19.992px

Comment: This is very strange. I have a Thinkpad t470p, Windows 10 Pro, and as you can see in my update, i have different values.

Comment: please use keys ctrl + 0 to resize browser to 100%

Comment: @yjs as I already mentioned, my browser is set to 100% (default)